# WebView a traves de setContentView

Tags: android-studio, webview-android

Hola gente vengo todo el día queriendo resolver esto.
Tengo una actividad Principal que tiene un WebView. Esta actividad esta atenta a la conexion a internet.
Al no tener conexion a internet se le setea un nuevo Layout que contiene un boton, para volver a reintentar conectarse.

Cambio de Layout usando setContentView(R.layout.sin_conexion);

Al volver a reintentar conectarme desde el boton de ese layout.
El WebView se queda en blanco. El Toast Responde y no se como hacer que el WebView se me vuelva a mostrar como cuando abro la APP.
Por favor alguien que me de alguna sugerencia, idea, ¿algo?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```js
 public void intento (View view){

        Toast.makeText(Web.this, "REINTENTANDO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl(url);
     }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al volver a cargar el nuevo layout debes volver a obtener la referencia de la vista, en este caso el `WebView` en el layout después de llamar `setContentView()` .

```
 public void intento (View view){

        Toast.makeText(Web.this, "REINTENTANDO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        //* obten la referencia del WebView
        web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.<id WebView>);

        web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl(url);
     }
```

Comment: Si!! te amé. Mil gracias era eso. Creí que como estaba en el onCreate no debia hacerlo de nuevo. Mil gracias.

Comment: Me alegra se haya solucionado el problema @JonatanPaez , saludos!